# Guess a number game using HTML and javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a simple script:

```js
var play = true;
var correct = false;
var number = 0;
var guess = 0;
while (play) {
  // random number between 1 and 10.
  number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 - 1);
  if (number == 0) number = 1;


  while (!correct) {
    guess = window.prompt("What is the number?");

    if (guess < number) {
      alert("Guess higher ;)");
    } else if (guess > number) {
      alert("Guess lower ;)");
    } else if (guess == number) {
      correct = true;
      alert("You got it!");
    }
  }

  if (window.prompt("Do you want another game?", "yes") != "yes") {
    play = false;
  }
}
```

When I get the number right and prompted to "Do you want another game?" and enter "yes", the program redisplays  and stuck at "Do you want another game?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the state of `correct` on every play loop:

```js
let play = true;

while (play) {
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
  let guess = 0;
  let correct = false;

  while (!correct) {
    guess = window.prompt("What is the number?");

    if (guess < number) {
      alert("Guess higher ;)");
    } else if (guess > number) {
      alert("Guess lower ;)");
    } else if (guess == number) {
      correct = true;
      alert("You got it!");
    }
  }

  if (window.prompt("Do you want another game?", "yes") != "yes") {
    play = false;
  }
}
```